# Hadoop FS Analysis Using Hive Queries

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have the following `hadoop fs image` fields loaded into my `hive` table.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hadoop_fs_images(
  Path STRING,
  Replication INT,
  ModificationTime STRING,
  AccessTime STRING,
  PreferredBlockSize INT,
  BlocksCount DOUBLE,
  FileSize DOUBLE,
  NSQUOTA INT,
  DSQUOTA INT,
  Permission STRING,
  UserName STRING,
  GroupName STRING
)
```

Now using `hive SQL` I would like to run some analysis and gather some health metrics. For example, to gather all path (or tables) that contain files that are smaller than `1 MB`, I could run something like this:

```
SELECT
    relative_size,
    accesstime,
    path AS total
FROM
    (SELECT
        ( CASE filesize < 1048576
            WHEN true THEN 'small'
            ELSE 'large'
        end ) AS relative_size,
        accesstime,
        path
    FROM
        hadoop_fs_images) tmp
WHERE
    relative_size = 'small'  LIMIT  100;
```

How do I calculate the following? :

1. Fastest growing tables
2. Largest growing tables
3. File size and File Distributions
4. Empty Folders